# On a unit disk, what is the expected distance between the midpoint of two uniformly random points, and the centre?

Tags: definite-integrals, circles, expected-value, average

On a unit disk, what is the expected distance between the midpoint of two uniformly random points, and the centre?

**Context**

I thought of this question after seeing a [simpler question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4567824/in-a-unit-circle-what-is-the-average-distance-to-the-center-of-circle): on a unit disk, what is the expected distance between a random point, and the centre? (The answer is $2/3$.)

**My attempt** (at my question)

I started by considering the one-dimension case: on a line segment of length $2$ (analogous to a unit disk, which has diameter $2$), what is the mean distance between the midpoint of two uniformly random points and the centre? I first considered that the line segment is discrete, with $n$ points, worked out the probability distribution, found the expectation in terms of $n$, then took the limit as $n\to\infty$, and I got $\int_0^1 x(1-x)dx=1/6$. But when I jump to the two-dimensional case (unit disk), this approach doesn't seem to work, because there are directions involved, not just distances.

I tried to find the probability density function of $X$, the distance of the midpoint to the centre, but I have not been able to work out what it is.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2946890/398708) to the question, "What is the expected distance between two points inside unit circle?", suggests that polar coordinates may be useful, but I have not been able to obtain an integral expression using polar coordinates.

Comment: See Crofton's method involving a differential equation, as explained [here](https://web.mit.edu/urban_or_book/www/book/chapter3/3.5.1.html) (excerpt from the book "Urban Operations Research", 1981,  Richard C. Larson and Amedeo R. Odoni)

Answer (score 1):

(Self-answering)

[image]

The diagram shows points two uniformly random points $A$ and $B$ on the disk, and their midpoint $M$. Their distances to the centre $O$ are $a$, $b$ and $m$, respectively. $\theta=\angle{AOB}$.

Intuitively, we can guess that $E(m)$ is exactly half of [the expected distance between two random points on a unit disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946673/expected-distance-between-two-points-inside-unit-circle?rq=1). That is, $E(m)=\dfrac{64}{45\pi}$. This is because the average value of $\theta$ is $\pi/2$, and the average value of $a/b$ is $1$, and with these values we have $m=\frac{1}{2}AB$.

In fact, using excel, I generated about $300,000$ pairs of random points on the unit disk, and found that $E(m)\approx 0.453$, which is $\dfrac{64}{45\pi}$ to 3 decimal places.

As for a proof that $E(m)=\dfrac{64}{45\pi}$, it can be shown that

$$m=\frac12\sqrt{5a^2+b^2-2ab\cos{\theta}-4a|b\cos{\theta}-a|}$$

The probability density functions for $a$, $b$ and $\theta$ are $2a$, $2b$ and $\frac{1}{2\pi}$, respectively. Therefore,

$$E(m)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ab}{\pi}\sqrt{5a^2+b^2-2ab\cos{\theta}-4a|b\cos{\theta}-a|}\text{d}\theta\text{d}a\text{d}b$$

I have not evaluated this integral, and I do not have the technology to approximate it, but based on the above evidence, I am confident that it equals $\dfrac{64}{45\pi}$.